# How to setup ICC and Bazel on Windows

Tags: windows, clang, bazel, icc, build-system

I setup my bazel environment on Windows, which uses clang by default. I found that `CROSSTOOL` allows me to set a compiler, but the documentation is very poor on this. Is there any resource available that explains how I can change the default compiler of Bazel to ICC on Windows?

The most promising solution I found is simply setting `CC` but `CC=icc.exe` doesn't invoke the compiler as expected and still uses clang. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen the [crosstool tutorial](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html)?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is more to it, eg. lib directories, includes